# Cupcake(API3) friendly way to pause/stop sound loops in SoundPool? Any ideas?

Tags: java, android, loops, android-1.5-cupcake, soundpool

Quick note: I'm using the SoundPool class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

What I have here is a simple button that plays a looped sound while it's pressed. It works great. However, `sounds.autoPause();` wasn't introduced until API 8 and I really need something that is cupcake compatible (API 3) So i was going through the dev reference site filtered by API 3 stuff and i saw pause so i figured i'd try `sounds.pause(sound);` but it doesn't stop the sound when i release it.(Maybe i'm just using it wrong?) Does anyone know of a cupcake friendly way to stop this sound? thanks!

edit: also tried `sounds.stop(sound);` that didn't work either.

The Code:

My onCreate:

```
sounds = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
sound = sounds.load(this.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.red_long_one, 1);
```

Then here's my touch event

```
@Override public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction() ) { 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                System.out.println("touch");
                sounds.play(sound, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                System.out.println("up");
                //autoPause does not work on anything lower than sdk8
                sounds.autoPause();
                break; 
            }

            return false;
        }
```

I don't understand why `sounds.stop(sound);` doesn't seem to work, that seems to but what any article i read recommends to do

I think it's worth noting that if i use `sounds.stop(sound);` it works ONE time then after that it won't stop after i let go. but the first press and release it works as intended.

Now, I know on the andoird site it says streamID and not soundID but i have no idea how to get the streamID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use streamID to stop a sound. streamID is returned by play():

something like that:

//record streamid when you play a sound
streamIDSoundFX=soundPool.play(soundFXPoolMap.get(ctSoundFX), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);

//stop it when you need
soundPool.stop(streamIDSoundFX);